# how to pick the correct NSPropertyListFormat

Tags: objective-c

what is the criteria of choosing the format ?

These are the  formats

- NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat
- NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
- NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0

Comment: i am looking for more detailed explanation of these formats

Answer (score 1):

Well, you almost certainly don't want the OpenStep format, so that leaves XML or Binary.  Do you want it human readable or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just pick `NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0` 
unless you have a reason to pick another one, then you wouldn't be asking this question.